# Xpath issues with content egg plugin

Tags: python

I don't usually post on here as you all seem pretty advanced for me, but this feels like an advanced question, so thought I'd ask.

I'm using the Content Egg plugin for `WordPress` (please don't roll eyes) and it's asking me for `XPath` for a price I'm trying to get. I have tried so many different xpaths and none of them seem to be working. I'm trying to get the price `Xpath` from this webpage. Any ideas?

https://www.hockeydirect.com/Catalogue/Hockey-Sticks/Young-Ones-Hockey-Sticks/Young-Ones-ABD-Hockey-Sticks/Young-Ones-ABD-70-Hockey-Stick-341111

This is what i've tried:

```
//html/body/form/div[5]/div[2]/div[3]/div/span/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/span/fieldset/div[1]/div/div[1]

//*div[@class="MainPriceContainer"]

//div[@class='MainPriceContainer vcenter']
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi @AndrewMcNamee , could you format your question to make it more readable? You can see here how it's done: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: Does Content Egg work on dynamic content? The price is not in the static HTML that's returned. It's generated by JavaScript live. You can extract it from `google_tag_params.ecomm_totalvalue` but that might be removed one day.

Comment: Thank you all. I'm not sure what that means, or how i do it, but i'll research it and find out.

Answer (score 0):

try to copy the xpath from firefox by this steps 
inspect elements and select the price with the selector pointer it will highlight the element in the inspector html 
then right click to the highlighted code then copy then select XPATH from inside copy 
then paste it to the Xpath
then set the price update in the offer module setting to 30 seconds and test 
if worked tell me :)

Comment: can you rephrase or reformat your response, very lengthy single sentence makes it hard to understand.  Please break your reply into meaningful short sentences.